# How can I improve my question on an obscure aspect of jQuery security?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I recently asked a question about security implications of a particular jQuery API:

[Is jQuery's $.get() safe to call on an untrusted URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29044209/781723)

I got 3 answers, but reading through them makes me think my question is not written clearly or I am not communicating effectively.  Does anyone have any suggestions how I can improve my question?  I'd like to make it as high-quality as possible.

I've tried to edit the question based upon the comments and answers received, but this has ended up making the question long, and I'm not sure whether it's very clear. Do you have any suggestions for how my question could be improved? Does it need more motivation, explanation in different terms, clarification of some specific aspect? Does it need more research effort? Is it too obscure or simply not all that great a fit for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Meta is the perfect place to seek help improving your question when you're not receiving suitable answers.

Comment: One problem with your question is that it's actually 14 questions (by my count). The Q&A format works best when there is a single clear question which has a definite answer. A few side questions is probably ok, but 14? It makes it hard for any would-be answerer if they know the answers to some but not all of your questions, and it also means the answer will lose focus because there isn't one single point to address.